# scala: what means this line in tail recursive function?

Tags: scala, list, tail-recursion

I have this tail recursive function which should get two lists and append them in a third list.

```
def append[T](as:List[T], bs:List[T]) : List[T] =
{
  def append_tailrec[T](as:List[T], bs:List[T], acc:List[T]) : List[T] =
  {
    as match
    {
      case x::xs => append_tailrec(xs, bs, x::acc);
      case (x::xs && as == Nil) => append_tailrec(as, xs, x::acc);
      case (bs == Nil) => acc;
    }
  }
  append_tailrec(as, bs, ?::?);
}
```

I do not understand the last line in any tailrecursive function like this one which is here `append_tailrec(as, bs, ?::?)` Is this for initialization purpose? I think I also heard that it is the last (recursive) call before finishing. Anyway, could someone explain this line to me in detail? Please don't give me hints how to write this function in another way. I just want to understand what the purpose of this line is and what I have to give here (where the question marks are). THX in advance!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. But basically that line is saying that the return value of `append` is calling `append_tailrec(as, bs, acc = ???)` So, basically it is the first call to the inner _(tail-recursive)_ function. What you should pass in the `???` is the initial value of the accumulator, what exactly it should be would depend on each function.

Comment: Where does this code come from? There are lots of problems with it, so perhaps look for a better example if you are just learning Scala.

Comment: @Tim this is my own code. Im tryin to understand scala. I made a similar example with only two lists (as, bs) where I just appended the elements of as to bs. This was absolutely no problem. But here I got stucked when I want to save both lists in a third list.

Comment: The last line doesn't do anything because it is not valid Scala code. (2 of the 3 `case` statements are also invalid.)

Comment: @jwvh sorry, but your hints do not bring me anything.

Comment: You are asking what this Scala code means. But it isn't Scala code, so we can't tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the correct append list to list function below:

```
def append[T](as:List[T], bs:List[T]) : List[T] = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def append_tailrec(listA:List[T], listB:List[T], acc:List[T]): List[T] = {
    listA match {
      case Nil => listB match {
        case Nil => acc.reverse
        case b :: bs => append_tailrec(listA, bs, b :: acc)
      }
      case a :: as => append_tailrec(as, listB, a :: acc)
    }
  }
  append_tailrec(as, bs, Nil)
}

println(append(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6))) // List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
println(append(List(3, 2, 1), List(6, 5, 4))) // List(3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4)
```

The inner function is tail-recursive, and line `append_tailrec(as, bs, Nil)` is calling inner function. Tail-recursive function is optimisation for scala-compiler, it's better then just recursive function.
In tailrec function you can accumulate result in acc argument, and in each recursive call you add new element to acc, from listA or listB if listA is empty. 
I think you should more read about recursion, tail-recursion, pattern matching and List data structure in scala. Good luck!